# How do I match a blank line using regex when using the global option (/g)?

Tags: regex

I'm aware the general question must have been asked many times, but in attempting the suggested solutions I'm getting nowhere. I'd like to match either a new line character without a preceeding > or a new line character on it's own, but I can't seem to get any of the usual suggestions for matching a blank line to work.

Example (pcre):

```
/(([^>])\n|^\n)/$2<br>\n/g
```

In:

```
Hello World!

<tag>
text
```

Out Generated:

```
Hello World!<br>

<tag>
text<br>
```

Out Expected:

```
Hello World!<br>
<br>
<tag>
text<br>
```

Editable here:
https://regex101.com/r/Vh30n9/4

I believe I'm missing something fundamental, the knowledge of which would probably allow me to update the question title to be more specific and helpful to others.

Comment: Like [`([^>]?)\n`](https://regex101.com/r/WD6eK5/1) (to replace with `$1<br>\n`)? What if there are 2 blank line on end? What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: If your regex flavor supports lookbehind then [Search for `(?<!>)\n` and replace by `<br>\n`](https://regex101.com/r/Vh30n9/5)

Comment: BTW, what is the regex flavor?

Comment: Hi, regex flavour is pcre (php), in the case of two empty lines, the expected behaviour would be to add a <br> to each. I can update the question if you have a solution to that, as just adding the multiline option seems to result in some lines missing a <br> when there are multiple consecutive blank lines.

Comment: If it is PCRE then my suggested lookbehind solution should work for you as well.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, you are correct and it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is right, but your options are wrong. You just need to turn on the multiline option so that ^ matches beginning of line, instead of beginning of document. You have the "/g" global option on now, which is correct. You just need to add the "/m" also (so it ends up being "/gm").

Comment: Ah, this explains why I've been struggling with matching the start and end of a string in general, thank you! I'll improve the title and award you the answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your regex flavor is PCRE (PHP) you can also use a negative lookbehind for this:

Search for regex:

```
(?<!>)\n
```

and replace using:

```
<br>\n
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vh30n9/6)

Here `(?<!>)` is negative lookbehind that asserts true only if there is no `>` character before `\n`.